# In WordPress, how do I get the number of posts next to single_cat_title(''); in the category.php file?

Tags: php, categories, count

In WordPress, how do I get the number of posts next to `<?php single_cat_title(''); ?>` in the category.php file?

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(''); ?> (<?php ????code to count number of posts in the category shown?>?? ?>)</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.

This code shows the number of posts on a page after clicking on a category in WordPress. Even if the post has lots of categories.

```
<?php $category = get_queried_object(); echo $category->count; ?>
```

I used this code as the code was in the category.php file and not part of the regular loop.

I hope this code helps anyone else if they are having the same type of problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found out I can use this <?php echo ($wp_query->found_posts) ?> in the category.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function get_category() to get the category object and then just simply echo the $count property value.

```
$cat_count = get_category( 'ID OR ROW OBJECT' );
echo $cat_count->count;
```

If you also want to get the category object or ID before that then use this code:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply here. I have a page with posts that look like this:

(Title:) Ice Festival
(Categories:) Activities, Activity, Cccc, English Post, Events, Hhhh, Lake Ssss, Winter
(Excerpt:) Blah blah blah. 
The problem is each post has about 10 to 20 categories. How would I get the category when it is clicked?